# How to route domain.com/locale/controller to domain.com/controller in Kohana?

Tags: php, localization, kohana, kohana-3, routes

I'm trying to implement localization in my website. Currently, the basic (English) website is at http://domain.com/controller/action and I want each localization to be at http://domain.com/locale/controller/action. Basically, if a user visit the latter URL, Kohana will use the same controller and action than for the English version. In code, I will simply swap the strings.

Currently, I tried by adding the following route but that didn't work:

```
// This is my default route:
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<overflow>)))', array('overflow' => '.*?'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

// This the route for the localizations:
Route::set('locale', '(<locale>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<overflow>))))', array('overflow' => '.*?'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

With this setup, if I visit http://domain.com/es/controller/action, I will get a 404 error. Any idea how I should setup my routes to make this work?

**Edit:**

Just to complete matino and John Himmelman's answer, if I simply swap the rules as suggested, it will work. However, the "locale" route would then become the catch-all route and you will *always* have to specify the locale, even if all you need is the default one (in my case "en" / English). To fix that, you can limit the "locale" parameter to the locales you support. For example:

```
Route::set('locale', '(<locale>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<overflow>))))', array('locale' => '(fr|zh|en)', 'overflow' => '.*?'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<overflow>)))', array('overflow' => '.*?'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

In that case, only URLs that start with "fr", "zh" or "en" will be supported. Additionally, unsupported locales will return a 404 errors, and "domain.com/controller/action" will correctly display the default, English locale.

Comment: Try swapping rules (the most general rule should come as the last one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kohana applies routes in the order they appear in your bootstrap. This is why your default/catch-all route should always be defined last.

From [KO 3.0 routing](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/routing) doc:

> It is important to understand that routes are matched in the order
>   they are added, and as soon as a URL matches a route, routing is
>   essentially "stopped" and the remaining routes are never tried.
>   Because the default route matches almost anything, including an empty
>   url, new routes must be place before it.

As suggested, swapping routes will resolve the issue.

```
// This the route for the localizations:
Route::set('locale', '(<locale>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<overflow>))))', array('overflow' => '.*?'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));


// This is my default route:
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<overflow>)))', array('overflow' => '.*?'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```